# Java Web Start console vanishes

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am a novice to Java Web Start. I have a sample Client-Server application with CORBA as a middle ware. The front end (Client) is in Java and back end (Server) is in C++. The application is run and tested with jar and batch file. Now I want to deploy that application in Java Web Start and JNLP.
I have configured the same by creating a JNLP file and signed jars.

Now as all knows any CORBA application needs a domain file ( .cfg ) and some org.omg classes to communicate with the server by RPC.

I am stuck with how to specify these domain file name, path, CORBA classes etc in my JNLP. Not even that, I can't understand exactly what configuration will make the CORBA apps work properly in Java Web Start so that it can communicate with the server as well. All the Orbix jars's, IDL Stub jars are present and signed. I am giving my JNLP file as a reference. Actually I have tried adding these domain files and CORBA classes as parameters. But as usual it is not working and after running the JNLP the Java console suddenly gets disappeared.

CORBADemo.jnlp

```xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://172.28.1.139:8400/Test_CORBA_App" href="CORBADemo.jnlp">
<information>
<title>CORBA Demo</title>
<vendor>Ushacomm</vendor>
</information>

<resources>
<j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/UI_Fall_Test63.jar" main="true" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/ConfigurationService.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/IDLStub.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/art-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/art.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_ip-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_ip.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_ip_cio-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_ip_cio.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_ip_nio-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_ip_nio.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_tls-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/atli2_tls.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/codeset.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/concurrency-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/concurrency.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/ifc-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/ifc.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/iiop.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/java_management_logging-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/java_mgmt_plugin-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/java_portable_interceptor-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/management-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/management.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/mgmt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/omg-rt.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/omg.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/perf_logging.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="lib_6.3-Signed/portable_interceptor.jar" download="eager" />
<property name="Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass" value="com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBImpl"/>
<property name="Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass" value="com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBSingleton"/>
<property name="ORBdomain_name" value="VOIAMODOMAINNEW"/>
</resources>

<application-desc name="CORBADemo Demo Application" main-class="Launch" width="300" height="300">
</application-desc>

<update check="background"/>

<argument>1</argument>

<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
</jnlp>
```

<

When I was running the apps from jar using batch file my batch file looks something like this

runJar.bat
C:\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\java -Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBImpl -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBSingleton -jar lib_6.3\UI_Fall_Test63.jar -ORBdomain_name VOIAMODOMAINNEW 1

pause

As you can see the following things are specified in the batch file :

1. JDK path : ( C:\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\java )
2. Java VM arguments for max and min memory : ( -Xms64M -Xmx512M )
3. ORB class name: ( -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBImpl )
4. ORB singleton class name : ( -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBSingleton )
5. Jar file name to run : ( -jar lib_6.3\UI_Fall_Test63.jar )
6. Domain Name : ( -ORBdomain_name VOIAMODOMAINNEW )
7. Main function args : ( 1 ) 
   All the libraries ( Orbix jar as well as other third party libs ) are placed in my lib_6.3 folder, as you can see I specified in #Point5 the jar location directory is lib_6.3. Similarily in web start I have signed all the jars by "jarsigner" and put them in lib_6.3_Signed ( as you saw earlier in my posted JNLP file )

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
// using JavaScript to get location of JNLP file relative to HTML page
var dir = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var url = dir + "CORBADemo.jnlp";
deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

After clicking the launch button jnlp downloaded in desktop. After running the jnlp, web start console disappears at a particular point. 
After investigating I found that in my application it is giving the prints before resolving the reference for CORBA Naming Service. Just while attempting to resolve "NamingService" and executing this code the problem occurs I presume.

org.omg.CORBA.Object initNCRef = i_objORB.resolve_initial_references("NameService"); -->"i_objORB" is "org.omg.CORBA.ORB" type object.

In the CORBA application resolving NamingService for ORB is facilitated by the following class which I used to specify in the batch file. You can see the batch file in my previous posts.
        -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBImpl

I could not understand why the console is getting disappeared. Even for that I gave print in my application to view the stack. But the console vanishes within a few seconds. I cannot understand why.

Comment: The JNLP is invalid.  Check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) and correct the errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in capturing the text from a vanishing window, you may enable logging.  Find this folder in Windows:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties
```

add these lines, using whatever directory you like in this format:

```
deployment.log=true
deployment.user.logdir=C\:\\tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about CORBA but I can see some problems comparing your jnlp-file with the command line you provided.

When setting properties in the jnlp file remove the leading "D". In the command line version you use

```
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBImpl
```

this essentially tells the jvm to set the system property "org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass" to "com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBImpl". So the name of the property really is "org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass" and that is the name you should specify in the property tag:

```
<property name="org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass" value="com.iona.corba.art.artimpl.ORBImpl"/>
```

The "-ORBdomain_name VOIAMODOMAINNEW 1" command line arguments are not set as system properties but given as command line parameters to the main class of your program. You should specify them in argument tags inside your application-desc tag like this:

```
<application-desc name="CORBADemo Demo Application" main-class="Launch" width="300" height="300">
    <argument>-ORBdomain_name</argument>
    <argument>VOIAMODOMAINNEW </argument>
    <argument>1</argument>
</application-desc>
```

I'm not sure if these changes are sufficient for fixing your problem but it may be a starting point.

To further diagnose the problem it might be helpful to start your webstart application from the command line like

```
javaws http://www.yourservername.com/yourpath/CORBADemo.jnlp
```

Answer (score 0):

smw is right, as you mistyped the ORB class & ORBSingleton class properties JavaIDL will be used instead of the intended Orbix ORB.

The heapsizes are set as attributes of the `<j2se initial-heap-size="..." max-heap-size="...">` tag in JNLP.

Note that from Java7u45 on you need to sign your JNLP file in order these properties to have an effect.